# Datetime Update format error Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, datetime

I have an italian format datetime string like this:

```
23/03/2012
```

the sql command of this update is this in the datetime part:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(Reg_tes.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

This works on my Sql server(Italian language) but if i make this on my server(English language) gives me this error:

> "the conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type
>   resulted in an out-of-range value"

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Since you provide `InvariantCulture` as `IFormatProvider` it should not matter if it's italian or english culture. Where do you get the exception? Do you use sql-parameters?

Comment: when i call the UpdateCommand that makes the Update in my table

Comment: Please show your update command.

Comment: Data_tessera='" + DateTime.ParseExact(Reg_tes.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) "'

Answer (score 1):

You should always use parameterized queries to prevent sql-injection and localization issues like this.

So i assume that you are passing this datetime as string to the database.

```
using(var con = new SqlConnection("connection-string"))
using(var cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE dbo.TableName SET DateColumn=@DateColumn WHERE PK=@PK", con))
{
    DateTime reg_tes = DateTime.ParseExact(Reg_tes.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithvalue("@DateColumn", reg_tes);
    // other parameters ...
    con.Open();
    int affected = cmd.executeNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: i use a string that brings the Updatecommand code and than i assign him to updatecommand:


data_mod.sql.UpdateCommand = dati;


(dati is the Update string)

Comment: @ItalianBadAss: So you don't concatenate your string to build the sql like `... SET DateColumn='" + DateTime.ParseExact(...) + "'...` ? Never do that.

Comment: yes i concatenate..i cant post it because is too big...but as i say before my command is ok on my local sql server..the update works..but not in the english sql server

Comment: @ItalianBadAss: Use parameterized queries instead, always. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html